# yii2 password encryption to send in network

Tags: security, rest, mobile, yii2

I am developing a yii2 website that also has a connected mobile app. I would like to know what is the recommended way in the client side, both the mobile and the web page to send the password during authentication? Obviously sending clear text is not a recommended way, so I would like to know what's the standard ways of doing it.

1. In the login form when the user login's with a plain password, do we encrypt and send it? if so what is the encyption standard that we should use?
2. In the mobile(IOS and Android), what encryption standard's they should use in the REST Api? (Im using yii2 REST API framework)

Answer (score 1):

Your should `POST` to an `HTTPS` URL.

The web browser and the mobile client should then do the magic for you.

PS: After successful authentication you should use something like an random/known authToken, instead of sending the password with every request.

Comment: The recommendation is not only to have the page post to https but to have the actual password changing page be on https.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **HTTP Basic Authentication, OAuth or Query parameter**

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-authentication.md